# what "Debug Assertion Failed" mean and how to fix it, c++?

Tags: c++, debugging, assertions

why this program gives me a "Debug Assertion Failed" Error Message while running

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "fstream"
#include "string"
using namespace std;

int conv_ch(char b)
{
    int f;
    f=b;
    b=b+0;
    switch(b)
    {
    case 48:
        f=0;
        break;
    case 49:
        f=1;
        break;
    case 50:
        f=2;
        break;
    case 51:
        f=3;
        break;
    case 52:
        f=4;
        break;
    case 53:
        f=5;
        break;
    case 54:
        f=6;
        break;
    case 55:
        f=7;
        break;
    case 56:
        f=8;
        break;
    case 57:
        f=9;
        break;
    default:
        f=0;
    }
    return f;
} 

class Student
{
public:
    string id;
    size_t id_len;
    string first_name;
    size_t first_len;
    string last_name;
    size_t last_len;
    string phone;
    size_t phone_len;
    string grade;
    size_t grade_len;
    void print();
    void clean();
};
void Student::clean()
{
    id.erase (id.begin()+6, id.end());
    first_name.erase (first_name.begin()+15, first_name.end());
    last_name.erase (last_name.begin()+15, last_name.end());
    phone.erase (phone.begin()+10, phone.end());
    grade.erase (grade.begin()+2, grade.end());
}
void Student::print()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
        cout<<id[i];            
    }
    cout<<endl;
    for(i=0;i<15;i++)
    {
        cout<<first_name[i];            
    }
    cout<<endl;
    for(i=0;i<15;i++)
    {
        cout<<last_name[i];         
    }
    cout<<endl;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        cout<<phone[i];         
    }
    cout<<endl;
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        cout<<grade[i];         
    }
    cout<<endl;

}


int main()
{
    Student k[80];
    char data[1200];
    int length,i,recn=0;
    int rec_length;
    int counter = 0;
    fstream myfile;
    char x1,x2;
    char y1,y2;
    char zz;
    int ad=0;
    int ser,j;
    myfile.open ("example.txt",ios::in);
    int right;
    int left;
    int middle;
    string key;
    while(!myfile.eof()){
            myfile.get(data,1200);
            char * pch;
            pch = strtok (data, "#");
            printf ("%s\n", pch);
            j=0;
            for(i=0;i<6;i++)
            {
                k[recn].id[i]=data[j];
                j++;
            }
            for(i=0;i<15;i++)
            {
                k[recn].first_name[i]=data[j];
                j++;
            }
            for(i=0;i<15;i++)
            {
                k[recn].last_name[i]=data[j];
                j++;
            }
            for(i=0;i<10;i++)
            {
                k[recn].phone[i]=data[j];
                j++;
            }
            for(i=0;i<2;i++)
            {
                k[recn].grade[i]=data[j];
                j++;
            }
            recn++;
            j=0;
    }


    //cout<<recn;
    string temp1;
    size_t temp2;
    int temp3;
    for(i=0;i<recn-1;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<recn-1;j++)
        {   
            if(k[i].id.compare(k[j].id)<0)
            {
                temp1 = k[i].first_name;
                k[i].first_name = k[j].first_name;
                k[j].first_name = temp1;

                temp2 = k[i].first_len;
                k[i].first_len = k[j].first_len;
                k[j].first_len = temp2;

                temp1 = k[i].last_name;
                k[i].last_name = k[j].last_name;
                k[j].last_name = temp1;

                temp2 = k[i].last_len;
                k[i].last_len = k[j].last_len;
                k[j].last_len = temp2;

                temp1 = k[i].grade;
                k[i].grade = k[j].grade;
                k[j].grade = temp1;

                temp2 = k[i].grade_len;
                k[i].grade_len = k[j].grade_len;
                k[j].grade_len = temp2;

                temp1 = k[i].id;
                k[i].id = k[j].id;
                k[j].id = temp1;

                temp2 = k[i].id_len;
                k[i].id_len = k[j].id_len;
                k[j].id_len = temp2;

                temp1 = k[i].phone;
                k[i].phone = k[j].phone;
                k[j].phone = temp1;

                temp2 = k[i].phone_len;
                k[i].phone_len = k[j].phone_len;
                k[j].phone_len = temp2;

            }
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<recn-1;i++)
    {
    k[i].clean();
    }
    char z;
    string id_sear;
    cout<<"Enter 1 to display , 2 to search , 3 to exit:";
    cin>>z;
    while(1){
        switch(z)
        {
        case '1':
            for(i=0;i<recn-1;i++)
            {
                k[i].print();
            }
            break;
        case '2':
            cin>>key;
            right=0;
            left=recn-2;
            while(right<=left)
            {
                middle=((right+left)/2);
                if(key.compare(k[middle].id)==0){
                    cout<<"Founded"<<endl;
                    k[middle].print();
                    break;
                }
                else if(key.compare(k[middle].id)<0)
                {
                    left=middle-1;
                }
                else
                {
                    right=middle+1;
                }
            }
            break;
        case '3':
            exit(0);
            break;

        }
        cout<<"Enter 1 to display , 2 to search , 3 to exit:";
        cin>>z;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

the program reads from a file example.txt

```
313121crewwe         matt           0114323111A #  
433444cristinaee     john        0113344325A+#  
324311matte          richee          3040554032B #
```

the idea is to read fixed size field structure with a text seprator record strucutre

Comment: While the folks here are generally helpful, you have to make it easy for us.  Show that you've done at least something about fixing the issue yourself.  Don't just give us all your code and make us wade through it and debug it for you.

If you want help, do this:  Like gf said, run your program in a debugger to pinpoint which line is a problem.  Then get rid of all the other lines of code until you're left with a small program that demonstrates your bug.  *That* we'll work on and help you understand what's wrong with it. But the code you posted, we won't touch it.

Comment: This code is horribly written. You need to make better use of objects, structs and functions and for loops.

Answer (score 7):

The assertion failure is thrown by one of the standard C++ library functions that you're calling with invalid parameters. Run it in a debugger and you should see exactly what call.

One thing that looks suspect: In `Student::clean` you make calls like:

```
first_name.erase (first_name.begin()+15, first_name.end());
```

If the length of `first_name` is less than 15, this is likely to cause an assertion failure or other errors.